# Creating circle in android andengine by box2d?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I can create rectangle for creating wall for example:

```
    final Rectangle wall = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH-2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT -2);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, wall, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    scene.attachChild(wall);
```

But i wanna create circle? for example ball.it should be body of box2d like above.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually pretty simple:

```
Body circleBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(pWorld, pSprite, BodyType.StaticBody, FixtureDef);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused with scene.attachChild();  Looks like it is not needed in such case.